# Exception when loading rtsp stream with OpenCV and Python

Tags: opencv, rtsp

When I try to load an rtsp stream  using

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov')
```

I get the following exception

VIDEOIO(cvCreateFileCapture_AVFoundation (filename)): raised unknown C++ exception!

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved by installing opencv with ffmpeg.

```
brew install opencv --with-ffmpeg -v
```